# Python Arrow timezone parsing

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-arrow

I'm trying to convert a string to DateTime object, The string:

`Saturday 8th of August 2020 07:48:11 AM CDT`

I'm using arrow package

```py
arrow.get('Saturday 8th of August 2020 09:23:34 AM CDT', 'dddd Mt[h] of MMMM YYYY HH:mm:ss A ZZZ')
```

I'm getting the following error

```py
arrow.parser.ParserError: Could not parse timezone expression "CDT"
```

I couldn't find any way to convert the CDN part into timezone.

Comment: Arrow gets its time zones from IANA via dateutil, per https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#t4. Is CDT included there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has said in the documentation, some abbreviations are ambiguous. You can use for example `America/Chicago` instead of `CDT`